# best php config / ini class?

Tags: php, configuration

I'm looking for an alternave to the parse_ini_file() function in php. I want a simple way to store config settings, but want the flexibility to store unlimited levels of multiple arrays, special characters, etc. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you end up going with the Zend option, or did you find a solution that doesn't require Zend?

Comment: with the project I was working on I ended up writing my own basic config class, but now I am using Zend as it is pretty easy to use and has some good extra features (one config file for dev / staging / production, etc.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Zend_Config_Ini](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.config.adapters.ini.html) would fit the bill nicely for this:

> $config = new Zend_Config_Ini('/path/to/config.ini', 'staging');
>
> echo $config->database->params->host;   // prints "dev.example.com"
>
> echo $config->database->params->dbname; // prints "dbname"